# How to create a summary table of an one2many table in OpenERP7?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I have tree models: `res.partner`, `my_category` and `partner_my_category_rel`. The relationship between partner and category is a *many2many*, but I needed to store some attributes in the relationship table (not only the IDs, but also the registration date), so, as you may know, I had to create the intermediate table by my self (I named it `partner_my_category_rel`). Therefore, in `res.partner`, I have an *one2many* field pointing to the table `partner_my_category_rel`.

Now I want to create a summary table. The summary table must show only one row per category (this row will be the one with the last registration date).

Example: a partner belongs to the category **gold** twice (with registration dates **19/09/08** and **31/12/09**) and to the category **silver** once (with registration date **20/04/13**. The summary table must show only two rows, one per **gold**, one per **silver** (**31/12/09** and **20/04/13**).

But I added a button **Open History** per line, to see all the records per category, so if I click of this button in the line with category **gold**, a pop-up will be opened and I will be able to see the two records of the category **gold** in a tree view.

Done (with a function field of type="one2many"). But they must be editable. Now my problem appears. If I start editing a record, even if I don't save the changes, when I close the form, no problem, but after doing that, if I switch to other partner and repeat the same process, I get a JavaScript error when closing the form:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined***

I tried two ways (adding the property `editable="bottom"` in the tree view of the history, and creating a form to be able to edit the records of the history clicking on them). The JS error appears in both cases.

I can't understand why (it's not about a specific record, because it doesn't matter the partner I open the first time, it's not going to spark an error, but the other ones I open later will do).

**Case with the edit form**

Code of the button **Open History**

```
def open_history(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Utility method used to add an "Open History" button in partner views """
    partner_my_category_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
    data_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    form_data_id = data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'res_partner_extended', 'partner_category_rel_edit_form_view')
    tree_data_id = data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'res_partner_extended', 'partner_category_rel_tree_view')
    form_view_id = form_data_id and form_data_id[1] or False
    tree_view_id = tree_data_id and tree_data_id[1] or False
    return {
        'name': _('History of "%s"') % partner_my_category_obj.category_id.name,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': False,
        'views': [(tree_view_id, 'tree'), (form_view_id, 'form'),],
        'res_model': 'partner.category.rel',
        'domain': '[("partner_id", "=", %d), ("category_id", "=", %d)]' % (partner_my_category_obj.partner_id, partner_my_category_obj.category_id.id),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'flags': {'tree': {'action_buttons': True},
                  'form': {'action_buttons': True},}
    }
```

Code of the **tree view**

```
<record id="partner_category_rel_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">partner.category.rel_tree</field>
    <field name="model">partner.category.rel</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Categories">
            <field name="registration_date" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Code of the **edit form view**

```
<record id="partner_category_rel_edit_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">partner.category.rel.edit.form</field>
    <field name="model">partner.category.rel</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Category" create="false" version="7.0">
            <group>
                <group col="4">
                    <field name="registration_date" required="1" />
                </group>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found a solution!!

The problem arose when I clicked on the button *Close*, *Discard* or *Save*, the popup was closed and the function field of type="one2many" had no time to be reloaded.

So I added an option to the function field:

```
<field name="summary" options="{'reload_on_button': True}">
   <tree>
      ...
   </tree>
</field>
```

The option **reload_on_button** seems to reload the function field each time a button which modifies it is clicked.

Thank you anyway for your help. Hope this helps to anyone!

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I believe your model design is wrong.

You want to have:

```
[Partner] -->N [Partner Category] -->N [Partner Category Dates]
```

Or maybe use a flatter model structure:

```
[Partner] -->N [Partner Category Dates]
```

In this last case you would have an additional calculated field `Is latest?`, `True` for the last record  of each Partner/Category, `False` otherwise. Using a filter on this field you could have the effect you want, and older dates are still stores and available to list. If could even consider using the `active` reserved field for that effect.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. I like your idea of using a functional field `is_latest`, this way I could use a one2many field with a domain `[('is_latest', '=', True)]` instead of using a functional field of type one2many (which I think is fishy of the JS error). I didn't understand very well the model you suggested me, but I'm going to try with that field and I'll comment the result.

Comment: I've tried to do the next: in `partner_category_rel` I've added a field named `is_latest`, a functional field of type boolean. It works perfect. The problem is again the button *Open History*, is still giving a JS error. I can't understand why!

Comment: You don't need that method: having the button run an XML Window Action with a proper domain should do it. You have on the record the all the fields you need for the domain filter: Partner and Category.

Comment: Thank you again @Daniel. I removed the python function and created an XML action, but exactly the same problem. If I click on *Open history* in any partner and then I close the popup, everything is OK. But if I go to the previous or next partner (clicking on the left/right arrow on the top right corner of the screen) and repeat the same process, when I close the popup the JS error arises. The only way I've found by the moment to fix this is turning the `target` of the action from `new` to `current`... this way the popup is not a popup anymore and when going back, there's no JS errors.